# Embed Text in Shape

Tags: actionscript

I would like to embed some text into a circle in ActionScript. I have three problems: I can't get the text to center in the circle, I can't get the text to be center aligned, and I can't get the font to be applied to the text. Regarding the font, I know that it is embedded correctly, as it works on `TextField`s I create on the stage.

```
[Embed(source="DAXCOMPL.TTF", fontName="DaxCompact-Light", mimeType='application/x-font', embedAsCFF='false')]
private var MyFont:Class;

public function Bubble(...) {
    var myFont:Font = new MyFont();

    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.size = 20;
    myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
    myFormat.font = myFont.fontName;

    var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var r:int = 30;
    var text:TextField = new TextField();
    text.text = "Hello world!";
    text.wordWrap = true;
    text.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    text.x = -30;
    text.y = -30;

    circle.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000, 1.0);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,r);
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    circle.addChild(text);
    circle.x = 75;
    circle.y = 450;
    addChild(circle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to initalize the textfield this way:

```
var text:TextField = new TextField();
text.embedFonts = true; // use embedded font
text.defaultTextFormat = myFormat; // use this command before setting text
text.text = "Hello world!";
text.wordWrap = true;
text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
text.x = -text.textHeight*0.5; //center the textfield after setting text
text.y = -text.textWidth*0.5;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, but this solved two of my three problems (vertically aligning my text and applying my font). However, the text is still not aligned in the center of the shape - it always ends up too far to the right. Does this work for you?